# MIPS can li and sb be combined into one instruction?

Tags: mips

I am new to MIPS so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I can't seem to find an answer to this question on the web. Can these two instructions be written as one instruction? The code I have below feels redundant:

```
li    $t0, 23
sb    $t0, 0x10010000
```

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: Why is it redundant? Those instructions are quite different. Its one of the consequences of Load / Store arquitectures

Comment: I think it feels redundant because I have a background in Java and am just starting MIPS. However, that is not to say that it is actually redundant since I am not familiar with MIPS. So then, my question to you is, is this the correct way to store an immediate in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they can´t be combined. There is no such thing as a "store inmediate to memory" instruction.

Mips implements a simple ISA. Being a RISC architecture, the only way to store a byte in memory is to use the `sb` instruction.